# View the top part of the text when applying css: "overflow: hidden;"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a timepicker, with the following elements:

- Up buttons for the hour and time;
- Two displays for next time, one for the next hour and the other for next minutes;
- Two displays for current time, one for the current hour and the other for current minutes;
- Two displays for the previous time, one for the previous hour and one for the previous minutes;
- Down buttons for the hour and time.

I'm trying to create the idea of ​​movement when you press any of the buttons.

This is the visual aspect I've achieved so far:

[image]

What I could not do:

- To present the upper part of the numbers, on the previous time displays.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it, using javascript, css, jquery and html?

To create the visual look of my timepicker, I used the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#th31").html("01");
$("#tm31").html("01");
$("#th3").html("00");
$("#tm3").html("00");
$("#th32").html("23");
$("#tm32").html("59");
} );
```

```css
.modal-pop-up-time{
  background-color: WhiteSmoke   ;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 52%;
  z-index:10001;
}
.flex-container{
  position: relative;
  /* Other styling stuff */
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #3498db;
}
.flex-container1{
  position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
  /* Other styling stuff */
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
.spinner {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.spinner-input-wrapper {
 display: flex;
}
.spinner-input {
 margin: 0 3px;
}
.inner-element{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  /* or 3d alternative if you will add animations (smoother transitions) */
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
}
.triangle-up,
.triangle-down {
 width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}
.triangle-up {
 border-bottom-width: 8px;
 border-bottom-color: #555;
}
.triangle-down {
  border-top-width: 8px;
  border-top-color: #555;
}
.div-overflow-hide{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.input-line-height{
  line-height: 10% !important;
}
.input-text-center{
  text-align: center !important;
}
.input-background-color{
  background-color:  DeepSkyBlue  ;
}
.input-background-color-white{
  background-color:  white  ;
}
.input-text-color{
  color: White; 
}
.div-center-element{
 margin:auto;
}
.div-ml-40{
  margin-left: 40% !important;
}
.div-mlr-5{
  margin-right: 5% !important;
  margin-left: 5% !important;
}
.div-ml-10{
  margin-left: 10% !important;
}
.div-ml-5{
  margin-left: 20% !important;
}
.div-tiangles-background-color{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="lib/noty.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div tabindex="-1" class = "modal-pop-up-time" id = "popupreg">
 <div class="spinner-input-wrapper div-ml-10">
  <div class="spinner div-mt-5">
   <label class="div-ml-5">HH</label>
   <div class="div-tiangles-background-color" tabindex="2">
    <div class="triangle-up div-ml-40" id="up4"></div>
   </div>
   <div class= "flex-container1" tabindex="1">
    <div tabindex="1" class = "input-text-center input-line-height inner-element div-overflow-hide input-background-color-white" id = "th31" ></div>
   </div>
   <div class= "flex-container " tabindex="2" >
    <div tabindex="2" class = "input-text-center input-background-color input-text-color inner-element" id = "th3" ></div>
   </div>
   <div class= "flex-container1" tabindex="1"> 
    <div tabindex="1" class = "input-text-center input-line-height inner-element div-overflow-hide input-background-color-white" id = "th32" ></div>
   </div>
   <div class="div-tiangles-background-color"  tabindex="2">
    <div class="triangle-down div-ml-40" id="down4"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class= "spinner div-mt-5">
   <label class="div-mlr-5" >:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="spinner divmarginhor div-mt-5" >
   <label class="div-ml-5" >MM</label>
   <div class="div-tiangles-background-color" tabindex="2">
    <div class="triangle-up div-ml-40" id="up5"></div>
   </div>
   <div class= "flex-container1" tabindex="1">
    <div tabindex="1" class = "input-text-center input-line-height inner-element div-overflow-hide input-background-color-white" id = "tm31" ></div>
   </div>
   <div class= "flex-container" tabindex="2">
    <div tabindex="2" class = "input-text-center input-background-color input-text-color inner-element" id = "tm3" ></div>
   </div >
   <div class= "flex-container1" tabindex="1">
    <div tabindex="1" class = "input-text-center input-line-height input-background-color-white inner-element div-overflow-hide" id = "tm32" ></div>
   </div>
   <div class="div-tiangles-background-color" tabindex="2">
    <div class="triangle-down div-ml-40" id="down5"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the number to "fit" in the white part?

Comment: Yes vincent-d, and the bottom part of the number to be hidden, and not the upper part of the number.

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/k2azdwmj/7/?

Comment: @JoseMarques Check my answer bellow and tell me if it's what you meant

Comment: Something like that! 
I'll try if I can apply to my code?

Comment: If you want to simplify it and not want the need for js, you can just limit it to three numbers (selected above and below): https://jsfiddle.net/k2azdwmj/10/

Comment: @Pete is working! If you want to put a quick answer , I'll accept your answer as the correct. This way closing the question.

Comment: why are there so many javascript libraries? if you have both bootstrap and jquery-ui, why not extend their respective plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using some absolute positioning and line-height:

```css
.timebox {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 2em;
  height: 4em;          /* only wants to be double the line-height */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 2em;           /* can be what you want */
}

.inner {
  height: 6em;                  /* timebox line-height multiplied by 3 (number of numbers */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.number {
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="timebox">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="number">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="number">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="number">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="timebox">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="number">
      21
    </div>
    <div class="number">
      22
    </div>
    <div class="number">
      23
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```